# 何かそのちょっと expression meaning

Tags: translation

何かそのちょっと

Could you please explain me this expression?

Comment: Without more context, all anyone could do is guess.

Comment: I am sorry, it's just part of a conversation but the person doesn't say anything else.

Comment: @bunny: it's still useful to mention words before and after this phrase since it's clearly a reaction to something the other party said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

何かそのちょっと can mean different things depending on the context because it is a combination of vague words -- "Somehow, well, kinda."

Possible meanings are:

"Well, how should I put it....?"

"That seems a little, um..."

"I do not know if I agree."

"Not sure if that is correct/good."

I could go on and on but will stop here.  If none of these seem to fit, please come back with further context of the conversation.