# Does ちょっと（笑）have some kind of meaning when said at end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOuP6jppdJs&t=3m21s

> だけど
> 戦闘で使うのは
> バンギラスとか
> (Tyranitar)
> ちょっと（笑）

There are so many sites that list the endless meanings of ちょっと. My guess out of 100 other theories is that maybe it's equivalent to saying 〜と思います. Or it just a feminine ending that really has no significance. I could go on and on but I just don't know for sure.

Comment: ^ でもビデオ見たらそんな意味で言ってないようですよ

Comment: These seem related: [何かそのちょっと expression meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13894/43676), [Declining an offer politely using ちょっと and 無理](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69213/43676), [ちょっと and/or むり: How to refuse an invitation with a specific reason?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14087/43676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the speech is cut abruptly in a way that doesn't let the listener know what she was going to say. Or maybe the ちょっと was her way of hesitating to say something. In other words, just a filler. She was basically saying "I like these cute pokemons but in battles I rather use Bangirasu [and other pokemons like that] [because...]". What came next is just a matter of guessing for us listeners.

She seems to say a few more words (which can be seen by the movement of her mouth) in the next one second or two, but we can't hear that because the audio is taken over by the narrator.

I would say this would have felt unnatural and incomplete if it was part of a normal conversation. If someone does that, the listener would say "...and?".

ちょっと as a polite refusal is possible in other context, but I don't think so in this context.